# Cannot resolve symbol "StringUtils"

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

I have downloaded "commons-lang-2.6.jar" and added to my java project but I can't use `StringUtils`. Is there another jar file I should download or I have to change something in the project structure?

Comment: R u getting any error? what is the exact issue when you say "But I can't use StringUtils"?

Comment: The error is "Cannot resolve symbol “StringUtils”"

Comment: What IDE? And did you just setup your jdk?

Comment: its intellij idea 12 CE, it works on windows with intellij idea 11.1 CE but not in mac. The thing is I import "com.sun.deploy.util.StringUtils" in windows and works, but in mac it doesn't work

Comment: Are you able to import other java classes on your mac? You may need to set the path for your jre?

Comment: yes, I fixed the problem but still don't know why it works on windows and not on mac. funny thing is in windows, I didn't even import anything and "com.sun.deploy.util.StringUtils" works, but in mac I have to import the apache commons.

Comment: Weird, did Ctrl+Alt+S try to import anything?

Comment: File menu > Settings > Code Style > Java > Imports

Comment: I am not able to find any `stringUtils` in http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/deploy/util/ package. Are you sure "stringUtils" you are mentioning is from this import only.

Comment: @Srinivas yes, when I comment it out, it gives me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [need](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) to import the `org.apache.commons.lang` package.

Comment: Thanx but it doesn't have StringUtils.

Comment: I have this code running using import com.sun.deploy.util.StringUtils in another machine but here it doesn't work.

Comment: As of latest versions of Apache Commons Lang, the [correct package](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) is `org.apache.commons.lang3`.